# Why angular material sidenav animation is slow on first time?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Iam developing a website for mobile devices only.

iam using angular material for sidenav, but on first time load like just after login on clicking the hamberger menu sidenav comes slowly,

the slowness is visible with a small jerk (ie., the animation not linear )
but after first time sidenav comes perfectly with linear animation timing.

my app.component.html

```
    <mat-sidenav
      #sidenav
      mode="over"
      (click)="toggleLeftSidenav()"
      class="sidenav_main"
      style="background: #fff"
    >
      <app-sidemenu></app-sidemenu>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

app.component.ts

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this._sideNavService.setSidenav(this.sidenav);
 }
  toggleLeftSidenav() {
    this._sideNavService.toggle();
  }
```

sidenav.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { MatSidenav } from "@angular/material/sidenav";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class SidenavService {
  private sidenav: MatSidenav;
  public setSidenav(sidenav: MatSidenav) {
    this.sidenav = sidenav;
  }
  public toggle(): void {
    this.sidenav.toggle();
  }

}
```

for closing side nav also iam using same toggle function.

my sidemenu mostly contains static items only.some contents is injected based on api response.

what is causing this issue?
how to fix this perfomance issue?any help or suggestions please?

Comment: The `router-outlet` inside the nav "can" be the problem - it hangs on your component which will be rendered.

Comment: @Flo i completely disabled the animation using [@.disabled]='true'; then the sidenav come and goes instantly.but i need animation for my sidenav

Comment: For me it's hard to say what's going wrong... It's possible for you to create a Stackblitz example? And for other people they will help: Can you show which browser you use (incl. version), which angular + material version?

Comment: iam in chrome browser.i pulled out router outlet from mat-sidenav-container and added below mat-sidenav-container then only sidenav is showing

Comment: Here https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#resizing-an-open-sidenav is a official example in Stackblitz available. Fork it, show me your problem. This sample works in default as well.